# How to connect to ubuntu 14 desktop from windows 7 over the internet?

Tags: linux, xrdp

im trying to connect to my work pc (ubuntu) from home (win 7) using Remote Desktop Protocol, but i cant't do it. Someone have this setup already running?

Any help would be appreciated :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use VNC to connect, tightVnc for windows machine and VNC server for Ubuntu machine, I usually go for that and it's working, just google it a little bit more.